# Nuget 'Unable to satisfy conflicting requests' but the package versions are exactly the same. What is the conflict?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm on macOS using dotnet cli version 6.0.403, running `dotnet restore` on a .csproj and getting the following nuget restore errors which I don't understand.  From what I can see all the requests for `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions` are all for the same version (>= 6.0.0).  What is the conflict?

> /Users/code/legacy/LEAF/IntegrationTests/IntegrationTests.csproj :
> error NU1106: Unable to satisfy conflicting requests for
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions':
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> project/LEAF.DistributedCache.NATS 1.2.0),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> project/LEAF.Components.Services.Registration.NATS 1.1.0),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> package/LEAF.Components.Services.Registration.Contract 1.0.0),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> package/LEAF.Components.Services.Registration.Contract 1.0.0),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> package/LEAF.Components.Services.Registration.Contract 1.0.0),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> package/LEAF.Components.Services.Registration.Contract 1.0.0),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> package/LEAF.Components.Services.Registration.Contract 1.0.0),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> package/LEAF.Components.Services.Registration.Contract 1.0.0),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> package/LEAF.Components.Services.Registration.Contract 1.0.0),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> package/LEAF.Components.Services.Registration.Contract 1.0.0),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> package/LEAF.Components.Services.Registration.Contract 1.0.0),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> package/LEAF.Components.Services.Registration.Contract 1.0.0),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> package/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 6.0.1),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> package/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 6.0.1),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> package/LEAF.Components.Services.Registration.Contract 1.0.0),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> package/LEAF.Components.Services.Registration.Contract 1.0.0),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> package/LEAF.Components.Services.Registration.Contract 1.0.0),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> package/LEAF.Components.Services.Registration.Contract 1.0.0),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> package/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 6.0.1),
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via
> package/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 6.0.1) Framework:
> (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)

Comment: Well, I just removed all project & package references from the project, cleared my nuget cache, and re-added all project & package references, and now I don't get these errors any longer.  I have no idea why that worked or what the error means, though, so if anyone knows what the "conflicting requests" the error message refers to, I'd be very interested.

Answer (score 0):

Also faced the same problem.
I needed to change NuGet packages to submodule git.
Suffered for a long time.
The problem was that the NuGet packages were not completely removed from the solution.
Removing packages through NuGet solutions helped.

[image: context menu screenshot]

Then remove NuGet packages.